# JavaScript RegEx not matching [

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a .LRC file parser for JavaScript and I've hit a snag. I have the following code:

```
var getTimecodes = new RegExp("\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\]", "g");
var testLine = "[00:25.03][00:38.86][03:36.98][03:50.64]but man you should've seen him";
var timecodes = testLine.match(getTimecodes);
var lineText = testLine.replace(getTimecodes, "");

console.log(timecodes);
console.log(lineText);
```

which according to my understanding of RegEx and several different RegEx testing sites, including one written entirely in JavaScript, I should be getting the following results:

> ["[00:25.03]", "[00:38.86]", "[03:36.98]", "[03:50.64]"]
>
> but man you should've seen him

Instead I am getting the following output:

> ["00:25.03]", "00:38.86]", "03:36.98]", "03:50.64]"]
>
> [[[[but man you should've seen him

Could anyone shed some light on this please? I've probably done something dumb but I just can't work out what it is...

Thanks,
YM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double `\\` in `RegExp` constructor:

```
var getTimecodes = new RegExp("\\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\]", "g");
```

OR simply:

```
var getTimecodes = /\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\]/g;
```

**Reason:** Since `RegExp constructor` takes a String therefore String needs one escaping and regex engines needs second escaping.

Comment: Ah crap, I feel dumb now. I must've been really tired considering I had just fixed this exact same bug in a different place about 30 minutes before posting.

Comment: Out of interest, in your second example, is that some special syntax that JavaScript has specifically for Regex? Or is it just a bare string or something?